# Multiline Private Cert File as Beanstalk ENV Var

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently migrated from Heroku to AWS Beanstalk.

I've stored private certs as Env Vars in Heroku and Node could slurp this up merely by using `process.env.MY_CERT` (No need to escape the String or read in a FileHandle, etc...)

Looks like EB doesn't let you do this. I've escaped every newline with `\r\n` and am then doing

`const myCert = process.env.MY_CERT.replace(/\r\n/gm, '\n');`

Oddly enough, my node logs still show the `\r\n` even after having the replace call.

Any ideas? There must be a better way to handle reading in Certs for EB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html shows a good way to store keys into S3. But how should Node go about reading in the files (is it assumed to just use S3 SDK just for that?)

Thanks!